# call a parameterized Junit test case from main method

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver

class containing test case

```
public class SeleniumTestcaseParameterized  {

WebDriver driver;

private String userName, password, baseUrl;

public SeleniumTestcaseParameterized(String userName, String password) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
}    
 @Before
public void setUp() {
}   
@Test
public void testSeleniumTestcaseParameterized() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "url");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(userName);
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password);
 }
 @After
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

class where the test case is called in main method

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter Username");
    SeleniumTestcaseParameterized c = new SeleniumTestcaseParameterized(name,name);
    junit.textui.TestRunner.run(c.getClass());

    }
```

I am unable to pass the parameters to test case from main.

Comment: Any error or any warning?? you can go through this link https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaUnitTesting.html

Comment: Class SeleniumTestcaseParameterized has no public constructor TestCase(String name) or TestCase()

Comment: i think you need to do `public class  SeleniumTestcaseParameterized   extends TestCase`